# Holomorphic function bounded in a sector with angle $>\pi$

Tags: cv.complex-variables

I know that according to Liouville’s theorem, if a holomorphic function is bounded on all of C, it is constant. This got me thinking if I could find holomorphic non-constant functions that are bounded in a sector. The first obvious example would be the exponential function which is bounded on the half plane where the real part is non positive. But I cannot think of any entire function that is bounded on a sector with angle $>\pi$. Can anyone find such a function? Or perhaps provide a proof that no such functions exists.

Comment: The Laplace transforms of $\exp(-x^\alpha) \mathbb{1}_{(0,\infty)}(x)$, with $\alpha > 1$, have this property, if I am not mistaken. I used this in a paper with Alexey Kuznetsov, see Lemma 2.14 in [DOI:10.1214/18-EJP134](https://doi.org/10.1214/18-EJP134).

Comment: Think of [the Mittag-Leffler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_function).

Comment: Any two angular sectors (of positive angle less than $2\pi$) are conformally equivalent, so if you can construct a bounded non-constant holomorphic function on one of them, then you readily get one on the other. This question is not of research level, so it would be more suitable at http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6):

Let $L$ be the boundary of the strip
$$ G := \{a + ib\colon a>0, -\pi < b < \pi\}, $$
parameterised in clockwise direction. Define
$$ F_0\colon \mathbb{C}\setminus \overline{G}\to\mathbb{C}; \quad z\mapsto \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_L\frac{\exp(e^t)}{t-z}{\rm{d}}t.$$
It is easy to see that the integral converges and is uniformly bounded (in fact tends to zero as $z\to\infty$). Furthermore, $F_0$ extends to an entire function of the complex plane, which has the desired property. See Gwyneth M. Stallard, The Hausdorff dimension of Julia sets of entire functions, Ergodic Theory Dynam. Systems 11(1991), no. 4, 769–777.

In a similar manner, Cauchy integrals can be used to construct entire functions that are bounded outside any given unbounded Jordan domain. See e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.3439 .

Comment: This method can give you an entire function bounded on any closed set whose complement contains a curve tending to infinity.